# Overflow multiplicando dois inteiros em BigInteger

Tags: java, matemática, int, biginteger

Estou iniciando os estudos em Java e tenho uma tarefa: gerar dois inteiros aleatórios e armazenar sua multiplicação. Para isso, tentei usar `long` e `BigInteger`. Porém o resultado desta multiplicação está sendo quase sempre negativo. Por quê?

```
int p = a.getN();
int q = b.getN();
BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(p * q);
```

O método `getN()` gera e retorna um valor aleatório.

Exemplo de saída para `p`, `q` e `n`, respectivamente:

```
1274403499
1155563989
-664855737
```

(pelo que entendi, deveria ser `1472654790899997511`, que usa algo em torno de 61 bits)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É simples, o código está multiplicado dois inteiros e passando para um método que irá criar um [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Quando a multiplicação de dois inteiros ocorre, há o *overflow* e dá o valor negativo.

Provavelmente a expectativa era que os inteiros fossem passados para número `BigInteger` e, aí sim, multiplicados. Resolve assim:

```
int p = 1274403499;
int q = 1155563989;
BigInteger n1 = BigInteger.valueOf(p);
BigInteger n2 = BigInteger.valueOf(q);
BigInteger n = n1.multiply(n2);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ogxEEr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ahaxdesz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/BigIntegerMultiplication.java).

Comment: falta apenas arrumar a linha 4: BigInteger n2 = BigInteger.valueOf(q);, está fazendo p^2. Mas a ideia está correta e consegui aplicar. Obrigado :-)

Comment: É verdade @eightShirt. Arrumado.